# jQuery horizontal menu animated is behaving strangely

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have a horizontal menu, I have applied a jQuery function on this menu which should create a slow effect when menu is expanded. Problem is that the jQuery function works exactly the opposite and the effect is applied only to the background-color. This is the function:

```
function mainMenu(){
alert("qqqqqqqpppppp");
$('ul#nav').find('> li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul')
        .stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
    });
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to add other function to hide list.

```
function(){ $(this).find('ul').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

It works "opposite" because it is a *toggle* and it starts off visible, so the first time you hover it will actually be hidden. Notice that it works correctly after the first time. Try `slideDown` instead of `slideToggle`.

You might also need to set the inner `ul`s to hidden first, something like `ul#nav ul{display:none;}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still not working, if I modify from slide toogle into slideDown the menu is expanding normally without animation. If I set in css display:none; is not expanding :(.

Comment: Works for me when I apply it to your live example. Hard to say what's wrong without seeing your new code, and preferably a live version of it.

Comment: I modified live example with your sugestion, pls check.

Comment: It's because your keybindings.js file is setting their positions to `left:-999em`, but never moving them back.

Comment: Also note that using `jQuery('#offers').attr('style', 'left:-999em');` effectively erases any other styles set on the element, which might cause problems for jQuery. Use `.css('left','-999em')` instead of `.attr(...)`.

Comment: I modified keybindings.js and it really worked but only once, if I pass over the cursor the second time the animation is not working :( check live example modified. Thank you very much.

Comment: Because the menu isn't hidden again after first being shown, it is only moved to the left out of view. Since it is still "visible", it is shown immediately without animation the next time.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?